# Java KeyListener not detecting all pressed arrow keys

Tags: java, keyboard, keylistener

I am working on a game which takes keyboard input, and a lot of the time you need several keys pressed at the same time. For example, you want to be holding down space to shoot, up arrow to thrust, and left or right arrow to turn. However, the arrow keys act very strangely. Most of the time the keypressed method will not recognize a third arrow key being pressed, and sometimes it is even weirder: it will detect the wrong key if other keys are being held. I understand that's pretty confusing so I made a program to show it:

```
package resources;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Keys extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
ArrayList<String> keyspressed;

public Keys() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(350, 100);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    f.add(this);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    t.start();

    keyspressed = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint(); System.out.println(keyspressed);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString(showKeysPressed(), 20, 20);
}

public String showKeysPressed() {
    String s = "Currently pressed keys: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < keyspressed.size(); i++) {
        s+= keyspressed.get(i) + "   ";
    }
    return s;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !keyspressed.contains("Up"))
        keyspressed.add("Up");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !keyspressed.contains("Right"))
        keyspressed.add("Right");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !keyspressed.contains("Left"))
        keyspressed.add("Left");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !keyspressed.contains("Down"))
        keyspressed.add("Down");

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        keyspressed.remove("Up");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        keyspressed.remove("Right");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        keyspressed.remove("Left");
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        keyspressed.remove("Down");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Keys();
}





@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Here are a few things to do with that program to show what I mean:
-Hold space, up arrow, and then try to press left or right arrow. (The program only displays array keys because that's what is being weird)
-With a little bit of time in between, hold space, up arrow, and right arrow so up and right are being displayed, and then as you take your finger off of right arrow, hold left arrow. If it is not just my keyboard, it will stay as right arrow being pressed.

So does anyone know what is causing this? Is it just my keyboard? This is really frustrating to try to work with gameplay-wise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that some keyboards have a limit on how many keys you can press down at the same time. :) For some older keyboards and even modern ones of low quality, the limit is two keys at once. The only way to fix this is to buy a better keyboard. Also there are "key sets" on your keyboard, so certain keysets may have issues when you try to press too many keys belonging to the set at once. I'm not sure if that's causing your problem, but I just want you to be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you try the program quickly? I'm curious if other people are getting the weird thing where it detects the wrong arrow key if I switch at the same time. Also I am able to press more than 2 letters at the same time, just not arrow keys. But maybe just the arrow keys on my keyboard are like that?

Comment: I'm able to press all 4 arrows at once: http://prntscr.com/6d9usa

Comment: I can get 5 so far...

Comment: Here is a web application (no download required) you can use to test your keyboard inputs using a helpful GUI: http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx

Comment: I used that GUI and it definitely seems like it is my keyboard to blame. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Use these library's instead 
http://ksquared.de/blog/releases/stable/keyboard_hook-0.3.zip
these have proper mapping of arrow keys and can efficiently detect multiple key presses, Although [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) is far better than this.